# Add a class to first li if last li contains class with cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PfKb/22/) works as intended, when the last li has a class on, the first li gets a class of first.

I am trying to use the same principle with the jQuery Cycle plugin.  If you have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/Y2muS/26/) you will see that the cycle plugin adds a class of activeSlide to the active slide. I have put some code in fidle which I thought would handle it but it looks as though maybe I have my logic wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only checking for the *activeSlide* class once, when the document is loaded. Wrap your logic inside a click handler on the rows and it should work:

```
$('#nav li').click(function() {
    if( $('.activeSlide').is('li:last-child') ) {
        $('li:first').addClass('first');
    }
    else {
        $('li:first').removeClass('first');
    }
});
```

[Click here for live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2muS/38/)

#### What if I want to check for the active slide on each interval of the cycle?

You can add a callback to the `after` option and run the logic there as well. Check out [all the available options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) for more information.

[Click here for a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2muS/40/)

Comment: +1 as adding your code to the original fiddle works. The fiddle you linked though doesn't inlcud that code.

Comment: I understand now thanks.  I have updated your answer to have the now working fiddle included.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl: That was peculiar, I was sure I pressed save. I just updated to the working Fiddle myself anyway :)

Comment: Looking at this one again @Codemonkey what would happen if there was a timeout in the cycle like in http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/Y2muS/39/ is there a way to handle it automatically (without the click?) or as you said earlier will this mean activeSlide will only be checked once?

Comment: @ak85: You put the logic into a function and add it to the `after` callback option. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: thanks @Codemonkey I have seen this page for but I was looking at the jQuery documentation rather than the cycle documentation for the answer. Thanks!